# Using the ScrollTo plugin to scroll to the element clicked on

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I want to use the ScrollTo plugin to scroll to the element that has been clicked on. So that the element that has been clicked on ends up at the top of the page. I have the following code:

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").hover(
        function(){
            $("#sbox").toggle("slow");
        },
        function(){
            $("#sbox").toggle("slow");
        });
        $(".jumbotron").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).ScrollTo();
        });

});
```

This throws the error:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery(this).ScrollTo()')
    (anonymous function) (scripts.js, line 10)
    dispatch (jquery-1.11.1.js, line 4641)
    handle (jquery-1.11.1.js, line 4309)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are trying to scroll the element itself while you want to scroll the window towards the element (or the iframe if inside an iframe).

The [documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com.br/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) specifies, in the case of scrolling whole window, we can use it's scroll as follows:

```
$.scrollTo(position, transitionSpeed,{...});
```

Leaving for us just a bit of changes for final result:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
   $.scrollTo($(this).position().top, 500); //gets top position of element
});
```

Tend for what is the need of positioning, this is an example

I've set up a fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/3M5fE/ with the working example, blue divs are the ones with scroll.

Comment: Scrolls properly for the elements with enough screen below but for certain elements there isn't enough screen. What do I do about that?

Comment: There's nothing to do, if there's no space below you couldn't scroll even manually, it will go the maximum it can go. http://jsfiddle.net/3M5fE/1/

Comment: It there a way I can add more 'screen' below so that even when the lowest element is clicked on, it scrolls to the top?

Comment: @haky_nash You could definetely set the height of the elements wrapper so it could fit it all, that does it, show your html if you need orientation

Comment: It has some Django and extends a bunch of other html pages. Hard to show. Can you show me an example please?

Comment: I added another div as wrapper of the elements, take a look in html and CSS blocks, test it with the element below: http://jsfiddle.net/3M5fE/2/

Comment: Thanks. But you have set a finite height of 1800px, that won't work for everyone, will it?

Comment: Correct, as I said you will need to figure that with your code, I can't just imagine what is needed for your system, if you will need it dinamically count how many posts and set it's height on the run, which is theme for a new question if help is needed

Comment: Yes. I need exactly that :)

Comment: Done! I figured it out. I took the last post on the page, wrapped it in a Django if conditional, wrapped it in a wrapper div and set its height to a 100 percent :)

Answer (score 0):

the plugin is called scrollTo with lowercase "s".

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").hover(
        function(){
            $("#sbox").toggle("slow");
        },
        function(){
            $("#sbox").toggle("slow");
        });
        $(".jumbotron").click(function(){
            $.scrollTo(this);
        });
});
```

It'd be safer to change those toggle() for either show() or hide() depending on the case.